# simple setuid binary exploitation

Tags: linux, exploit

I have a setuid program which is listing a file this way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
        system("ls /challenge/binary/binary1/.passwd");
        return 0;
}
```

What I need is to get the program to disclose the content of the file instead of simply listing its name. So I tried to create an alias to alter the behavior of **ls** this way:

```
alias ls='cat'
```

but still, it's not working. Could you please point me to the right direction!

Comment: Why not change `system("ls` by  `system("cat` ? Are you trying to get a way to abuse a program using the system command to do something it's not supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aliases only live on the shell that defined them, and `system` starts a new shell. That shell won't read `~/.bashrc` or other files where aliases are typically defined, either: only interactive shells do. Some shells, but not all, read another file, but there's a shell-independent way of exploiting this.

Shell command lookup tries the following elements in this order:

- Aliases — no.
- Functions — no, for the same reason.
- Builtins — no.
- Commands in the `PATH` — it has to be this by default.

So work on ensuring that the lookup of `ls` in `$PATH` will turn up the `cat` program.

Answer (score 0):

Change `ls` to `cat`.

`ls` lists directories, it doesn't display files.  `cat` does that.

Comment: nop, that's not the question! I have a compiled version of a setuid program, and I have to alter the behavior of a program to use cat instead of ls without having to change the setuid program

Comment: Actually, in fairness to ultrasawblade, xe answered the question as written.  You made no mention of not having the source.  Indeed, in the question as asked you _provided_ the source.  Nor did you mention that you're trying to hack someone else's program.  Poor ultrasawblade isn't telepathic.

Comment: the title is fairly explanatory!